# Remove save feature in cocoa document-based application

Tags: cocoa, xcode, browser, save, document

I am currently working on a web browser project from [Apple's Mac Dev site](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/mac/2004/01/23/webkit.html).

I have completed the project, but have a bit of a problem. I have created the project as a Document-Based Cocoa Application, and now whenever I enter text in any text field on the web, the red traffic light button shows a black dot in the middle that signifies an unsaved document. When I try to close the window or entirely quit the application, a warning pops up like that in TextEdit or Pages where it alerts me to unsaved changes. It's not too much of a problem, but I would like if someone could please tell me how to remove that feature of a Cocoa Document-Based Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why a document based application if your application isn't document based?  Document based applications inherently include the concept of `open` and `save`;  it is a fundamental part of what they are.

In any case, you *could* "work around" this by configuring `NSDocument` appropriately;  override the proper methods and otherwise muck with the change count & dirty state of the document.   But it'll be just that, a workaround.   The documentation for `NSDocument` has all the information you need.

A cleaner overall solution would be to refactor your app to not use `NSDocument`.   Creating multiple windows is quite straightforward in Cocoa (an action method tied to a menu item where the action method loads a nib file;  if I remember correctly, you could even use `NSWindowController` still).

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution would simply be to override the `isDocumentEdited` method to always return NO.

```
- (BOOL)isDocumentEdited {
    return NO;
}
```